# Adiabatic proces derivation - differentation step (easy)

Tags: calculus, physics

[image]

I'm a little confused about this step

I have this idea that it is differentiated, using the product rule - but i can't really figure out the steps. Is the fraction split in two or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
 \frac{d \frac{p \cdot V}{n \cdot R}}{dV} = \frac{d}{dV} \left[ \frac{pV}{nR} \right] =  \frac{1}{nR} \left( \frac{d}{dV} [p V] \right)
\end{align*}
(provided that $n$ and $R$ are independent of $V$). Now using the product rule treating $p$ and $V$ as functions of $V$ gets you the desired result:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{nR} \left( \frac{d}{dV} [p V] \right) = \frac{1}{nR} \left(\frac{dp}{dV} \cdot V + p \cdot \frac{dV}{dV}  \right) = \frac{dp}{dV} \frac{V}{nR} + \frac{p}{nR} \frac{dV}{dV}
\end{align*}

Comment: Simple as that - thanks man